# Laravel Default Auth with Modals

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to modify laravel's default authentication system by using modal windows and by adding some new fields.
So, I have a modal window to register a new users which looks like this:

```
<!-- Modal Register area -->
<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myRegisterLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="formRegister" class="login-form" action="{{ route('register') }}" method="POST">

        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myRegisterLabel">Sign Up</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="first name..." value="{{ old('first_name') }}" required autofocus>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="last name..." value="{{ old('last_name') }}" required autofocus>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email..." value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password Confirmation:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Register
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      @if(count($errors))
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>{{ $error }}</p>
          </div>
        @endforeach
      @endif
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Modal Register area -->
```

Then I modified the RegisterController validation rules and the create method to include this new fields as well as the migration file. (So, I have the fileds in the database, everything's good there)

RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the form as you can see I'm posting this to route('register') but even though I'm not getting any errors when I submit the form and I get redirected to the / the user is not getting saved in the DB.. 
The thing is, I'm not really sure how this default auth system works..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you add the field to your $fillable property on the model?

Comment: Yes, I did, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: So on your make and create, where's the new fields you're adding?

Comment: Probably worth showing your model too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think provided code is pretty correct. Make sure you deleted `name` field form `users` table in your migration.

Using your code I was able to register a user with your modal and controller. Was fresh Laravel 5.4, your modal was placed in `welcome.blade.php`. Also css/js files added & a button to show modal.

Here is my `up()` migration for update `users` table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('name');
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Also updated `User` model with new fillables:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name'
];
```

Comment: Hmm.. What I did was after I ran make:auth to make the default authentication I went directly into the users migration and I removed the 'name' field and after that I added my first_name, last_name. Following that, I ran php artisan migrate. Should this be the problem?

Comment: yes you could modify existing migration, if if was not ran before. so this should not be a problem

Comment: Ok, I finally was able to get this running and I feel so silly now haha.. The problem was with my modal, I forgot I put a validation of min:6 on my password and I was entering a 4 characters password.. Because the modal closes after submit I didn't noticed that. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @OvidiuG ok have a nice day!